# Is there a way to create and flush I/O streams in try-with-resources?

Tags: java, stream

Is it possible to use the new `try-with-resources` statement in Java 7 to create both the `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` at the same time, and also flush the output stream *before* the input stream is created? Right now, I'm using the old style:

```
ObjectOutputStream ostream = null;
ObjectInputStream istream = null;
try {
  ostream = new ObjectOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
  ostream.flush();
  istream = new ObjectInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());
  // ...
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
  // Close the streams.
}
```

I'd like to know if there's a better way to create and flush the streams using the new style in Java 7. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it can be done but a down vote is harsh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could nest two try-with-resources: the outer one which opens the output stream and flushes it, and then inner one which opens the input stream.

Comment: I like your idea of nesting the second `try-with-resources` statement. I just implemented it right now. Thanks!

Comment: You missed what I missed as well: the `ObjectOutputStream` does write the "the serialization stream header" to the underlying stream in it's constructor.  If you don't flush that, you end up with problems.  The `SocketOutputStream.flush()` is a no-op.  The `ObjectOutputStream.flush()` is not a no-op.

Comment: @JB - remove your first paragraph (it's just wrong), and I'll remove the down-vote :-)

Comment: @RichardSitze: I missed the serialization header, but I don't see why you would need to flush before opening an input stream? Flushing after would have the exact same effect, wouldn't it?

Comment: Read the javadoc for `ObjectOutputStream(OutputSteam out)`, and tell me what you think.  Also consider denshaotoko's response to my (now deleted) answer: "There is a possibility that when you create the ObjectInputStream, it will block during its creation. I know for sure that if you tried to create it first before you create the ObjectOutputStream, it will block. I tried it. :) – denshaotoko".

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I've learnt something today. I'll update my answer.